# Cannot set property 'textcontent' of null

Tags: javascript, html

for some reason with this I get the error: Cannot set property 'textcontent' of null for this line:

```
 document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
```

```js
function countdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  var eventDate = new Date(2018, 1, 19);
  var currentTime = now.getTime();
  var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
  var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;
  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  var d = Math.floor(h / 24);
  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;
  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
  document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

  document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;

  document.getElementbyId("minutes").textContent = m;

  document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
}
countdown();
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="value">Ends in:
    </span>
  <p id="days">30</p>
  <p id="hours">10</p>
  <p id="minutes">5</p>
  <p id="seconds">1</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is that line? `document.getElementbyId("minutes")` you have an error where the `b` should be uppercase.

Comment: It looks like countdown() function runs before html snippet you've posted has been actually loaded and as a consequence,element with id "days" could not be found and getElementById returns null, which, obviously, does not contain property, specified in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that the element may not exist at the time your "countdown" runs... Could you try calling countdown onload of the body / div that contains the set of elements you're querying?

```
<body onload="countdown()">
```

Comment: Using JavaScript within the html like that has become poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue that I see is that your `b` needs to be uppercase on this line:

```
document.getElementbyId("minutes").textContent = m;
```

When fixing that the code works as expected:

```js
function countdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  var eventDate = new Date(2018, 1, 19);
  var currentTime = now.getTime();
  var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
  var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;
  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  var d = Math.floor(h / 24);
  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;
  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
  document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

  document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;

  document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;

  document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
}
countdown();
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="value">Ends in:
    </span>
  <p id="days">30</p>
  <p id="hours">10</p>
  <p id="minutes">5</p>
  <p id="seconds">1</p>
</li>
```

Make sure that your code is ran after the dom has finished loading.

you can do so like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => countdown());
```

Comment: That typo wouldn't cause this error, it would cause a different error.

Comment: My answer says that there is no error in the code, other than the typo. I also say that the code needs to run after the dom.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error: `getElementById` instead of `getElementbyId`.

The new code will be:

```js
function countdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  var eventDate = new Date(2018, 1, 19);
  var currentTime = now.getTime();
  var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();
  var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;
  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  var d = Math.floor(h / 24);
  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;
  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
  document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

  document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;

  document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;

  document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
}
countdown();
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="value">Ends in:
    </span>
  <p id="days">30</p>
  <p id="hours">10</p>
  <p id="minutes">5</p>
  <p id="seconds">1</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add defer in your HTML where you have inserted script tag.

Comment: Please give more details, for instance provide the code with the suggested changes